# The oracle profile variable, PS1

Tags: oracle

After I finish to install ORACLE, then there is the step that I have to register some environment values. One of them is PS1.

```
export PS1=$'\\n[$LOGNAME@\h:$ORACLE_SID]'
```

Kind of an explanation is "User OS prompt setting variable".

I can't understand when it is used and the variable is also quite weird.
Does anyone have an idea for it?

Comment: PS1 is used by the Unix Shell, Bash. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32096/why-is-bashs-prompt-variable-called-ps1 A good explanation: https://www.linuxnix.com/linuxunix-shell-ps1-prompt-explained-in-detail/

Comment: For people who use shells to access multiple servers, it can be quie useful to have the hostname in the prompt for example. That way, you don't truncate a vital table on prod! :-) - never happened to me of course!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no bearing on database administration. Better suited for https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"have to" - says who? It is not a mandatory requirement.

[5.1 Bourne Shell Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables)

> PS1 - The primary prompt string. The default value is ‘\s-\v\$ ’. See
>   Controlling the Prompt, for the complete list of escape sequences that
>   are expanded before PS1 is displayed.

[6.9 Controlling the Prompt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)

```
\n - A newline.
\h - The hostname, up to the first '.'.
```

`LOGNAME` (login name) and `ORACLE_SID` are custom environment variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It wasn't mandatory.. I didn't know it.